# Bluetooth HM-10 android bonding

Tags: android, arduino, hm-10

Need advice/help on what I might be doing wrong.

**What I have:**

Plugged in a HM-10 module to my Arduino.

-Factory Default settings except connection type:

--Using AT+TYPE3 (3:Auth and bond ).

Android LG G4, running Android 6 (Marshmallow) .

**Issue:**

Bluetooth HM-10 is visible to connect to in Android when searching for Bluetooth devices but when using the default pairing code "000000" "Wrong PIN or passkey. Try again?" message keeps coming up.

**What I tested:**

Windows 10 laptop bonds with the HM-10 device. (Verified MAC address by running AT+RADD? ) 

AT+TYPE0 (0:Not need PIN Code  ) connects via BLE Scanner app.

Asked three different people with different Android phones for help:

-Newest Samsung phone: Bonds

-Older Samsung phone: Bonds

-OnePlus One phone: Does NOT bond

**Hypothesis**

Bluetooth library on the devices that cant connect might be lacking handshake protocol when talking to the HM-10 module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm newer of these module HM-10,HM-16, and I meet same problem too.
Finally I found install APP "msmble" in android app store can solve this problem and do some simple test, like send word.
I guess protocol or UUID is the reason, but I don't know the detail.

There's another issue, no matter how I change the PIN setting. msmble always no need to enter PIN code.

Yu-Sheng